# Regex to match path containing one of two strings

Tags: regex, alternation

RegEx to match one of two strings in the third segment, ie in pseudo code:

```
/content/au/(boomer or millenial)/...
```

##### Example matches

```
/content/au/boomer 
/content/au/boomer/male/31 
/content/au/millenial/female/29/M 
/content/au/millenial/male/18/UM
```

##### Example non-matches

```
/content/au
/content/nz/millenial/male/18/UM
/content/au/genz/male
```

I've tried this, but to no avail:

```
^/content/au/(?![^/]*/(?:millenial|boomer))([^/]*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a look ahead; just use the plain alternation `millenial|boomer` then a word-boundary:

```
^/content/au/(?:millenial|boomer)\b(?:/.*)?
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/eR0nQmNVXsBxFk).

You should probably spell [millennial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennials) correctly too (two "n"s, not one).

Comment: The `\b` is not entirely strict; it will still match on `millenial.com` or `boomer*x`.

Comment: @tripleee sure, you could swap out `\b` for `(?=/|$)`, but `\b` works for all of OP’s cases and there’s readability to consider too.

Answer (score 1):

What's with the negative lookahead?  This is a simple, if not trivial, positive match.

```
^/content/au/(?:millenial|boomer)(?:/|$)
```

The final group says the match needs to be followed by a slash or nothing, so as to exclude paths which begin with one of the alternatives, but contain additional text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex [DEMO](https://regexr.com/652jm)

```
content/au/(?:boomer|millenial)
```

[image]