# What is the correct MongoDB function that will return True/False if words are not in a string?

Tags: mongodb

I have run the following code below and am getting a logic error in the MongoDB shell.
The result for string that contains 'rocket' (a true condition )should say 'contains words' but I am getting the result 'does not contain words' (a false condition).

I need some help finding the correct MongoDB function that will return True/False if words are not in a string.

```
db.Tweets.aggregate([{$project:{_id: 0, tweet: 1,convert:
{$cond: { if:{"$in":["$tweet",[/Tesla/i,/rocket/,"coffee"]]}, 
then: "contains words", else: "does not contain words" }}}}])
```

[image: incorrect result from condition]

```
db.Tweets.aggregate([{$project:{_id: 0, tweet: 1,convert:
{$cond: { if:{"$in":["$tweet",["Tesla","rocket","coffee"]]}, 
then: "contains words", else: "does not contain words" }}}}])
```

[image]

If you can see what I am doing wrong with this code I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/#-regexmatch--aggregation-)

Comment: Hi Joe $regexMatch works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I can get the $regexMatch to work on one word pattern, just need to figure out how to do it on more.    db.Tweets.aggregate([{$project:{_id: 0, tweet: 1,convert:{$cond: { if: { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /rocket/ } } , then: "contains words", else: "does not contain words" }}}}])

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69069038/regex-to-match-path-containing-one-of-two-strings

Answer (score 0):

$regexMatch suggested by Joe works perfectly.

I had to code each regex pattern separately and put them inside an $or operator. The $or operator returns the True/False to the $cond if, and I get the correct result for the then: "contains words" or else: "does not contain words"

```
db.Tweets.aggregate([{$project:{_id: 0, tweet: 1,convert:{$cond: { if: 
{
   $or: [
      { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /Tesla/i } },
             { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: /rocket/ } },
             { $regexMatch: { input: "$tweet", regex: "coffee" } }
   ]
}

, then: "contains words", else: "does not contain words" }}}}])
```

[image: ContainsWords]